# iOS Objective-C: Using URLConnection multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an array of objects.  My object contains a URL(`NSString`) and an image (`UIImage`).  I call a webservice to populate all the urls for the images and then I want to asynchronously get the image and update the object with the image.

I am stuck while I am trying to determine the index of the array which I need to update when the data is received from URLConnection.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the NSURLConnection to your Array. You could either subclass NSURLConnection to add a member, wich allows storing a tag identifier, such as an index.

Probably it would be simpler to create a NSDictionary, where each NSURLConnection acts as key and the arrayIndex in an NSNumber would be stored as the value.

In the callback-method you are using, you could access your dictionary with the according NSURLConnection as its key.

```
int arrayIndex = [[myDictionary objectForKey:urlConnection] intValue]
```

Comment: thanks. Makes sense.  I am going to try this approach and see how it goes.  I'll post back

Comment: This maybe a stupid question but how do I get the value to put in the dictionary?  I can see it in the DidFinishLoading but not when i am making the call..

Comment: You should store the dictionary as a member variable. Then, when you create your NSULRConnection you store that reference in the dictionary.

Something like that (alternatively using an array for your several NSURLConnections):

`NSURLConnection *urlConnection1 = ...;

[_urlConnectionDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:urlConnection1];`

Probably better using an Array and a loop to initialize your differen URL-Requests instead of using numbered variable names. But the concept stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

For getting UIImage from net use this instead of URLConnection multiple times.

```
 UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL of the image"]]];
```

Then load your image asynchronously in the UIImageView.

Comment: This will block the main thread! He needs to load the images asynchronously.

Comment: this is how i was doing it originally and realized i needed to do it with URLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use GCD to download image in background. Here is the tutorial if you want to refer:-  http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/

Following is the Code you can use:-

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [yourImageView setImage:image];
    });
});
```